# LIBGDX infinite RepeatAction interrupt

Tags: java, libgdx

I need to write a build-highest-stack game, there is a block moving site to site, after typing `SPACE` it should drop down on already built stack.

```
SequenceAction overallSequence = new SequenceAction();
    overallSequence.addAction(Actions.moveTo(0, block.getY(), 0.5f));
    overallSequence.addAction(Actions.moveTo(800 - block.getWidth(),
            block.getY(), 0.5f));
    RepeatAction infiniteLoop = new RepeatAction();
    infiniteLoop.setCount(RepeatAction.FOREVER);
    infiniteLoop.setAction(overallSequence);
```

There I got problem, after `SPACE` event need to break that loop and start new action, dropping block on stack.

I tried using `Action.sequence`, action set clearing and resetting, but with no considerable result.

Answer (score 1):

I tried doing it in Your way, but there are some thread-problems

```
[xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has 
not been called 
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
java: xcb_io.c:165: dequeue_pending_request: Assertion
`!xcb_xlib_unknown_req_in_deq' failed.
```

Comment: Can't say what that is. Do you use multi-threading? Consider opening a separate question, because the code in my answer has nothing specific and shouldn't cause this.

Answer (score 0):

To break the moving site to site loop just clear actions of the block `Actor`. So overall you can do this:

1) Infinite moving `Action`:

```
Actor block = ...;
block.addAction(
        Actions.forever(
                Actions.sequence(
                        Actions.moveTo(...),
                        Actions.moveTo(...)
                )
        )
);
```

2) When `space` key is pressed:

```
block.clearActions();
// drop the block
block.addAction(Actions.moveBy(...)); // or block.addAction(Actions.moveTo(...));
```